# LINQ to SQL : Delete a new added child entity before submitchanges - fails

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a parent child relationship very similar to Northwind Customer/Orders but with one differnece , CustomerID in Orders table can not accept NULL , it is a FK , the child has one column PKey called OrderID

I use this model in a windows forms databinding , upper area is having customer info in text boxes , lower area is having a grid with orders listed

I retrieve a customer using LINQ from DB to allow the user to edit customer info or order details , when i delete a row from the order grid then submit changes , i receive error 
"An Attempt was made to remove a relationship Between a Customer and Orders, However , one of the relationship's foreign keys (CustomerID) can't be set to Null"

after a long search on the internet , i used the DeleteOnNull=True attribute and it now works

What is not working however and still give same exact error is when i add a new order to the grid then delete it before SubmitChanges

I understand that when i delete a new order row in the grid i only remove the association to customer, so it sets CustomerID=NULL for that entity , fine , now how do it remove it entirely from the entity set before submit changes to avoid the error , i can't use DeleteOnSubmit because it is a new entity not came from db , i will receive an exception if i tried , so deleting the row by hand using the grid does not work which is calling "Remove" method i guess , and i can't use DeleteOnSubmit , what can i do ?

why it has to be that difficult? at ADO.NET datatable is much easier, if i delete a row and it happends to come from db then it marks it for deletion, if it is a new row then it removes it from the collection, Done! i don't want to go back to Datasets after investing many efforts learning LINQ to SQL now

any help is very appreciated

Thank you
Bassam

Comment: Can you tell me whether you are using a WinForm application or a Web application? Having trouble understanding what are you doing when adding or deleting a row in the Orders datagrid.

Comment: Although I believe the author mentions he is using WinForms, I have the same situation in ASP.NET MVC.  I have a scenario where the MVC default model binder is creating a child entity that I (based on certain conditions) wish to NOT have persisted to the database. I do not wish for it to ever exist in fact, but it is in my object graph. If I use ".Remove()" -- for example Customer.Orders.RemoveAt(0) to use the author's schema --  then it seems OK until I SubmitChanges, at which point  I get an error about a foreign key that cannot be set to null....

Answer (score 2):

I discovered what the problem is and solved it. I want to share the info here if someone else is having the same issue

First i want to mention an important fact: If Cascade Delete is enabled in the DB , then

```
DeleteOnNull:=True , DeleteRule:="CASCADE"
```

will be auto inserted in the code behind the .dbml file without the need to manually add `DeleteOnNull=True` for a specific association.

The problem is, there was another `FKey` in the child entity for the `OrderType`, which is `OrderTypeID`. I set this value like this:

```
Dim NormalOrderType = (From ot in db.OrderTypes Where ot.OrderTypeID=1 Select ot).Single
NewOrder.OrderType = NormalOrderType          
OrdersBindingSource.Add(NewOrder)
```

When a user deletes an order from the grid for a specific customer, LINQ to SQL sets the CustomerID `FKey` to NOTHING, breaking the association to the parent entity. BUT, it does **not** set `OrderTypeID` to NOTHING, keeping the other association active to `OrderTypes` entity. With an `OrderType` entity already loaded in memory, LINQ to SQL will think that i still want to insert the child entity but with `CustomerID=Nothing`, and since this is not allowed (as from the dbml file, `Nullable=False`), it will raise an exception before it tries to save to DB in the first place.

This problem is solved by doing this:

```
NewOrder.OrderType = NOTHING
```

This manually removes the association for the other `FKey`. Then, simply removing the child entity will cause LINQ to SQL to ignore it when `submitChanges` is called.

Thank you
Bassam Muhammad.